In Android Studio's Compose Animation Preview screen, how can I save the initial and target preview values of an animation?
Android Studio's Compose Animation Preview lets you visualize how an animation will look in a timeline. I'm using animateFloatAsState in this example and my usage will go from -1.0f to 1.0f. The thing is that the preview screen will have the same start and target values (-1.0f), which is useless, and reset after every preview reload, which is annoying as it forces me to set it again every time I edit my code. Is there a way to save the intended preview target value (1.0f) as it looks in the image permanently?

I looked up @Preview annotations but it doesn't seem that there's any helpful parameters.
